# Change woocommerce string

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

im trying to change woocmmerce string and I can't find any information.
In the products catagory there is a string that count the number of products in the category.
I want to change it from "Products: X" to "Number: X".
Someone can help my with it?
The CSS class of this string in "count" under "woocommerce-loop-category__title"
Thanks.

[the string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pk7Xy.png)
 Products
BTW im using Astra theme.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can learn more about [ask] a question to better support the folks who can help you with your question.  Please post what you have tried and the unwanted behavior you are seeing. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to find the string and change it through Loco translate plugin but without success